# R survival package; plotting log(-log(survival)) against log(time)

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I'm trying to use the R survival package, to produce a plot of `log(-log(survival))` against log(time)

<sub>(This is something sometimes recommended as a way to visually inspect for accelerated lifetime or proportional hazard properties).</sub>

The "`fun=cloglog`" option in `plot.survfit` is not producing what I expect it to.

Using the "gehan" data from the "MASS" library:

first, here is a simple plot of survival against time, for the treatment and control groups:

```
 data(gehan, package="MASS")
 gehansurv=Surv(gehan$time, gehan$cens)
 plot(survfit(gehansurv ~ gehan$treat), col=c("black", "red"))
```

[image]

OK so far. Now, if I use the `fun=cloglog` option, the documentation for plot.survfit makes me think that I'll get a plot of `log(-log(survival))` against `log(time)`:

> fun
>
> an arbitrary function defining a transformation of the survival curve. For example fun=log
>   is an alternative way to draw a log-survival curve (but with the axis labeled with log(S) 
>   values), and fun=sqrt would generate a curve on square root scale. Four often used 
>   transformations can be specified with a character argument instead: "log" is the same as 
>   using the log=T option, "event" plots cumulative events (f(y) = 1-y), "cumhaz" plots the 
>   cumulative hazard function (f(y) = -log(y)), and "cloglog" creates a complimentary log-log 
>   survival plot (f(y) = log(-log(y)) along with log scale for the x-axis).

However, when I try this, it doesn't seem to use the `log(-log(y))` function, because the displayed curve is still decreasing (since the original survival curve is decreasing, and the applied `f(y)=log(-log(y))` function is a decreasing function, the resulting `log(-log(survival))` curve should be increasing).

Also, the x-axis is not log-scaled:

```
library(VGAM)
 plot(survfit(gehansurv ~ gehan$treat), col=c("black", "red"), fun=cloglog)
```

[image]

I can get what I want by defining my own `log(-log())` function and using the `log="x"` option:

```
> myfun=function(p){return(log(-log(p)))}
> plot(survfit(gehansurv ~ gehan$treat), col=c("black", "red"), fun=myfun, log="x")
```

[image]

So: What am I doing wrong above (or how am I misinterpreting the `plot.survfit` documentation)?

Supplementary question: how would a `"fun="` option change the scaling on the horizontal axis as the documentation claims that `"fun=cloglog"` would, when on the face of it the argument to `"fun"` is a function applied to the vertical variable?

Comment: When I run code above I get "error: object 'cloglog' not found".  You must have had an object in memory called cloglog when you ran it.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, I had loaded the VGAM package which has a "cloglog" object.

Comment: Also thanks embert for adding the images for me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Put quotes around cloglog for plot.survfit.

```
library(survival)
library(MASS)
data(gehan)
gehansurv=Surv(gehan$time, gehan$cens)
plot(survfit(gehansurv ~ gehan$treat), col=c("black", "red"), fun="cloglog")
```

[image]

Comment: Oh! that is embarrassingly simple :) Thanks. Indeed, I had the VGAM package loaded, and it has a function cloglog.